# Tilemap from Tiled not rendering in Phaser

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm stuck in a rut with this game I'm trying to make. The tilemap I'm trying to use has an error stating as follows

```
Error 1: "Phaser.Tileset - image tile area is not an even multiple of tile size"
Error 2: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined"
Error 3: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"2
```

Here is a link to the code I'm using. http://pastebin.com/Dv00KGii

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code you have tried so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and tip, I'm going to do just that.

Comment: Once an edit has been made, ping me in the comments again, and I can vote this back up. You are already showing community participate by responding, that is excellent! Participation is the key to success around here!

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot exactly put the entire code here as it is restricted due to character space. My code exceeded the character limit as all characters in total are about 4400. Any tips for me?

Comment: Well, try to post _some_ code relevant to ther error, I mean all of it cannot be suspect, can it? But you should be able to use http://pastebin.com/ - Paste your code, give the Paste a Name, and hit Submit. It will give you a unique URL that you can post here.

Comment: @Madness Thanks, ok I', fixing it now.

Answer (score 5):

Try embedding tileset in your tilemap. For me this fixed this eror: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined"`

Answer (score 4):

Inside the Tiled Map Editor, you need to assure that all the tileset images that you are using are embedded inside the tilemap .tmx project file. If any of the tileset images is included as an external .tsx, not embedded image then it will throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined"` error when you will try to import inside the Phaser the exported JSON file from the Tiled Map Editor.

If you have forgotten to embed it at the beginning it is not a problem as you can always do it later. The editor has a useful icon to do it easily:

[image]

To see if you have any external tilesets that will produce this error, check if the exported tilemap JSON files contain any references to .tsx files.

Answer (score 1):

The error Phaser is reporting is the following:

"image tile area is not an even multiple of tile size"

So, apparently Phaser requires that the size of the tileset image is a multiple of your tile size. Tiled itself does not require this, but if you're using Phaser you should probably make sure there is no extra space in the tileset image.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to adjust the tiles and I'll replace the folder. thanks for the input, I'm very new to this and I would like this to be my first completed project. I shall report back on anything.

Comment: I don't understand, if I cover the entire area with tiles, is it possible to assign transparency to certain tiles with their specific id? I need some tiles to be solid but others to be passable for a working game.

Comment: It's not about a tile being transparent or not, but for example about whether the width of the tileset is evenly dividable by the tile width, I believe.

Comment: @ThorbjørnLindeijer Hello, I'm having this problem too. Can you please explain what this means? My tile size is 32 by 32 pixels, with a map height of 6 and a width of 48. In Phaser, my map is rendered like so `new Phaser.Game(768, 384...` which are both multiples of 32? What am I missing?

Comment: @ThorbjørnLindeijer If you say the size of the tileset image, does that mean each tile or the whole file?

Comment: @SummerDeveloper The tileset image is the whole image, usually containing multiple tiles on a grid. The error message suggests that the dimensions of this image have to be an even multiple of the dimensions of the tile. So if your tiles are 32x32, an example of a valid tileset image size would be 64x128, since this means it contains 2x4 tiles, which are both even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me. I found that my png image I was loading was 1280x720.

The example on Phaser [website](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/loader/load-tilemap-json) says to load the tilemap like this

`map = game.add.tilemap('mario');`

The documentation for the tilemap function is [here](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.GameObjectFactory.html#tilemap). The function takes other parameters like the tile sizes. In my case the default 32x32 is invalid because `720/32 = 22.5`. That number needs to be a round number. So I just cropped my image to `32*22 = 704`. Then Phaser was able to load the png with the default tilemap settings. So then the default 32x32 will work otherwise you can change the height setting to 10 since 720 is divisible by 10. In that case Phaser should not throw an error. In my case I resized my image because the other tile images I was using were all 32x32 so it is easier to be consistent.

Also when creating the tilemap json it is best if the `tileheight` and `tilewidth` are multiples of your image and settings.